# Problems starting a freshly installed Mean Stack application

Tags: gruntjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to start a new mean stack application. However i only get this error when I'm running `grunt` to start the server:

```
[nodemon] v1.2.1
Running "watch" task
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Waiting...
Debugger listening on port 5858
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;      
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at processResults (/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1581:31)
    at /Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1619:20
    at /Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1157:7
    at /Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1890:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)
    at /Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:439:20)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/olehenrik/Sites/learn/mean_test2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:201:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Have any one encountered this before? Can't find too many other people who have encountered this before.

Comment: Could you post more of the code? I think it maybe related to DB calls.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same error and this info solves it.

"Upgrade to 3.8.23. 3.8.22 introduced better compatibility with mongodb server 3.0 by upgrading to latest version of the driver." credit to vkarpov15 from mongoose Github thread.

What I did was I edit my package.json to upgrade mongoose to "3.8.23". After I edited the package.json I ran npm install and bower install(just to make sure) again and that solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome. While links are great to not copy the content into the answer, they may also become orphan if the resource is deleted or moved. So it is good practice to summarize the content linked in the answer.